# How webservice JAX RPC client works with a service secured by OWSM

Tags: java, web-services, soap, ws-security

First of all, sorry for this long post but I am brushing my mind on this since days without success. I really seek your help.
    I am trying to invoke a webservice which is secured by OWSM. Below are the policy assertions specified in the WSDL.

```
*************************************
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="service.BindingQSPort_Fault_Policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"/>
    <sp:SignedElements xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"/>
    <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"/>
    <sp:EncryptedElements xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"/>
</wsp:Policy>

<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="service.BindingQSPort_Input_Policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
        <sp:Body/>
        <sp:Header Name="fmw-context" Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/fmw/context/1.0"/>
        <sp:Header Name="" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
        <sp:Header Name="" Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"/>
    </sp:SignedParts>
    <sp:SignedElements xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"/>
    <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
        <sp:Header Name="fmw-context" Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/fmw/context/1.0"/>
    </sp:EncryptedParts>
    <sp:EncryptedElements xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"/>
</wsp:Policy>

<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="service.BindingQSPort_Output_Policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
        <sp:Body/>
    </sp:SignedParts>
    <sp:SignedElements xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"/>
    <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"/>
    <sp:EncryptedElements xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"/>
</wsp:Policy>

<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="wss10_x509_token_over_ssl_service_policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
        <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:InitiatorToken>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Always">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:X509Token>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:InitiatorToken>
            <sp:RecipientToken>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Always">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:X509Token>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:RecipientToken>
            <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:Basic128/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
            <sp:Layout>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:Lax/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Layout>
            <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
            <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
            <sp:ProtectTokens/>
        </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
    <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
        <wsp:Policy/>
    </sp:Wss10>
</wsp:Policy>

  <wsdl:message name="svcFault">
        <wsdl:part name="payload" element="WL5G3N2:fault"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="sendSMS">
        <wsdl:part name="payload" element="WL5G3N1:sendSMS"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="sendSMSResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="payload" element="WL5G3N1:sendSMSResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="service">
        <wsdl:operation name="sendSMS">
            <wsdl:input message="WL5G3N1:sendSMS"/>
            <wsdl:output message="WL5G3N1:sendSMSResponse"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="svcFault" message="WL5G3N1:svcFault"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="service.Binding" type="WL5G3N1:service">
        <WL5G3N3:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#wss10_x509_token_over_ssl_service_policy" wsdl:required="false" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"/>

        <wsdl:operation name="sendEmail">
            <WL5G3N3:operation style="document" soapAction="sendEmail"/>
            <wsdl:input>
            <WL5G3N3:body use="literal"/>
            <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#service.BindingQSPort_Input_Policy" wsdl:required="false" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
            <WL5G3N3:body use="literal"/>
            <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#service.BindingQSPort_Output_Policy" wsdl:required="false" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"/>
            </wsdl:output>

            <wsdl:fault name="svcFault">
            <WL5G3N3:fault name="svcFault" use="literal"/>
            <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#service.BindingQSPort_Fault_Policy" wsdl:required="false" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:binding>
*************************************

I have written a JAX-RPC client which is using "weblogic.wsee.security.bst.ClientBSTCredentialProvider" to provide client credential as required by the service. Below is the security related code.

*************************************
serverCert.checkValidity();
cp          =   new ClientBSTCredentialProvider(
                    clientKeyStore, clientKeyStorePass,
                    clientKeyAlias, clientKeyPass,
                    "JKS", serverCert);
l_credproviders.add(cp);

Stub stub   =   (Stub)port;
stub._setProperty(WSSecurityContext.CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_LIST
                    , l_credproviders
                    );
stub._setProperty(WSSecurityContext.TRUST_MANAGER
            , new TrustManager() {
            public boolean certificateCallback(
            X509Certificate[] chain,
            int validateErr) {
                // Check that the server cert matches
                boolean result = true;//chain[0].equals(serverCert);

                return result;
            }
        }
    );
*************************************

I am testing my client using SOAPUI. However above client code is giving me below Exceptions.

**************************************
java.rmi.RemoteException: SOAPFaultException - FaultCode [{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}InvalidSecurity] FaultString [Error on verifying message against security policy Error code:4206] FaultActor [null]No Detail; nested exception is: 
**************************************

Can someone please help me to understand what my WSDL is specifying and why "ClientBSTCredentialProvider" is not able to attach the required policy? Or is is happening that since I am testing with SOAPUI, SOAPResponse is not as per the WSDL policy? Below are the SOAP requests and response for this.

***************************************
~~SOAP REQUEST~~
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:MessageID wsu:Id="MessageID_HUf02VXDqusotArv" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">uuid:c7404e48f626d447:-246df928:14183ec2b7f:-8000</wsa:MessageID><wsa:Action wsu:Id="Action_CcS8Hy0hmQ2wVKHH" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">sendSMS</wsa:Action><wsa:To wsu:Id="To_bb3aIWjwG1Got1IZ" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">http://domainname:8090/sendSMS</wsa:To><wsa:ReplyTo wsu:Id="ReplyTo_w1ZItNbfV8se2kbF" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address></wsa:ReplyTo><wsse:Security env:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="bst_zM6y3VGAX9jZAaiV" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><dsig:Signature xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><dsig:SignedInfo><dsig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><dsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><dsig:Reference URI="#MessageID_HUf02VXDqusotArv"><dsig:Transforms><dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></dsig:Transforms><dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><dsig:DigestValue>oG0PCOutUmUrhIhjsHB2G9Nu7Qc=</dsig:DigestValue></dsig:Reference><dsig:Reference URI="#Action_CcS8Hy0hmQ2wVKHH"><dsig:Transforms><dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></dsig:Transforms><dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><dsig:DigestValue>jwnM3Pu8lEpk7WLokAfW/LcR8bM=</dsig:DigestValue></dsig:Reference><dsig:Reference URI="#To_bb3aIWjwG1Got1IZ"><dsig:Transforms><dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></dsig:Transforms><dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><dsig:DigestValue>9RzmvWQQJG853YKPzwoWDUjWze8=</dsig:DigestValue></dsig:Reference><dsig:Reference URI="#ReplyTo_w1ZItNbfV8se2kbF"><dsig:Transforms><dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></dsig:Transforms><dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><dsig:DigestValue>FPYcJ1NcK6nX5nx5cF+Jj5I2PZE=</dsig:DigestValue></dsig:Reference><dsig:Reference URI="#Timestamp_H75m9X5C1O9rNV2E"><dsig:Transforms><dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></dsig:Transforms><dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><dsig:DigestValue>ZAoaTp1B5yQv/ZGM6Pd8dfmNyPg=</dsig:DigestValue></dsig:Reference><dsig:Reference URI="#Body_q8jxTBg8ZRE0VjRO"><dsig:Transforms><dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></dsig:Transforms><dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><dsig:DigestValue>tnn+BbvQz/kuDBocU8Po24hn8W4=</dsig:DigestValue></dsig:Reference><dsig:Reference URI="#bst_zM6y3VGAX9jZAaiV"><dsig:Transforms><dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></dsig:Transforms><dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><dsig:DigestValue>IG2FZBY/Oqtsu4H6sl/6f2iHJx8=</dsig:DigestValue></dsig:Reference></dsig:SignedInfo><dsig:SignatureValue>LaXCIcrxyatPzcAsKJGK28TEgaEOUdoXUrcmucjHrZDuErfGPS5fa9LrIX7irGYYDoYjJ5uQLq7a7nSRcazfNPznf03nISgr6Voc+23HON2E+fyRmHkKJzWe6OxHRPyHYmxbYQzgXkwGCKqLOZVLJsQLQykMiNV8YK3vuacDAdU=</dsig:SignatureValue><dsig:KeyInfo><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="str_gp0ybJxTKkZntAn1" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:Reference URI="#bst_zM6y3VGAX9jZAaiV" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></dsig:KeyInfo></dsig:Signature><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp_H75m9X5C1O9rNV2E" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsu:Created>2013-10-04T14:43:16Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2013-10-04T14:44:16Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp></wsse:Security></env:Header><env:Body wsu:Id="Body_q8jxTBg8ZRE0VjRO" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><ent:sendSMS xmlns:ent="http://www.banqueaudi.com/evs/ent.msg.Notification"><util:header xmlns:util="http://www.banqueaudi.com/ebo/util.cmn.EBMHeader"><util:ebmSID>FCDB</util:ebmSID></util:header><ent:body><msg:smsNotification xmlns:msg="http://www.banqueaudi.com/ebo/msg.Notification"><msg:sender>98989898</msg:sender><msg:recipients><msg:recipient>78831471</msg:recipient></msg:recipients><msg:subject>SUBJECT</msg:subject><msg:message>My message</msg:message></msg:smsNotification></ent:body></ent:sendSMS></env:Body></env:Envelope>
***************************************

***************************************
~~SOAP RESONSE~~

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ent="http://www.banqueaudi.com/evs/ent.msg.Notification" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:util="http://www.banqueaudi.com/ebo/util.cmn.EBMHeader" xmlns:util1="http://www.banqueaudi.com/ebo/util.cmn.Basic">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"/></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-45" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><xenc:EncryptedData Id="ED-2" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"><wsse:Reference URI="#EK-B692F44E26CFCF96A613807927256684"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedData></soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
***************************************
```

Answer (score 2):

I found resolution to my problem, which I successfully tested with SOAP-UI. Will keep posted once it works on live though.

There are following points that first we should know before writing a client for OWSM secured webservice.

1. It is feasible to call JAX-WS service using JAX-RPC client and vice-versa.
2. It is feasible to invoke a OWSM secured webservice, with JAX-RPC client without installing/ configuring OWSM at client side.
3. Following is the client code (only related to security) for referecnce.

---

ist                             l_credproviders = new ArrayList();
        CredentialProvider              cp      =   null;

```
    cp          =   new ClientBSTCredentialProvider(MyClientKeystore.pubCertAlias, MyClientKeystore.prvKeyAlias, MyClientKeystore.serverPubCertAlias);
    l_credproviders.add(cp);

    Stub stub   =   (Stub)port;
    stub._setProperty(WSSecurityContext.CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_LIST
                            , l_credproviders
                            );

    stub._setProperty(WLStub.POLICY_COMPATIBILITY_PREFERENCE
                            , JFProperties.getProperty(
                                    "POLICY.COMPATIBILITY.PREFERENCE")
                            );

    stub._setProperty(WSSecurityContext.TRUST_MANAGER
                            , new TrustManager() {
                                    public boolean certificateCallback(
                                            X509Certificate[] chain,
                                            int validateErr) {
                                            // Check that the server cert matches
                                                return true;
                                            }
                                            }
                        );
```

---

1. How client credential provider API wotrks to secure a client: 
           a) It connects to the URL and parse the WSDL. 
           b) Get the policy assertions from the WSDL.
           c) create SOAP request message considering the client policy assertions.
           d) send and receive the response from the server.
           e) validate response from server against the policy assertions of server                       response from already parsed WSDL, If server response is not valid against policy throws SecurityExceptions.

Hope this help and someone gets benefited from my exhausted experience :)